# Unexpected end of string when removing key from hstore

Tags: postgresql, casting, hstore

When I am removing a key from a HSTORE, I get the error 'Unexpected end of string':

```
DB=# UPDATE mytable SET properties = properties - 'key'  where label = '9912345678';
ERROR:  Unexpected end of string
LINE 1: UPDATE mytable SET properties = properties - 'key'  where ...
```

When I explicitly cast that string, it does work:

```
DB=# UPDATE mytable SET properties = properties - 'key'::text  where label = '9912345678';
UPDATE 1
```

Why does it give this error message? Isn't `'key'` a `TEXT`  column? Or at least a string with a expected end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator is overloaded so the right-hand operand should be explicitly cast. Note the example usage for `text`, `text[]` and `hstore` in [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#id-1.11.7.25.5)

```
'a=>1, b=>2, c=>3'::hstore - 'b'::text
'a=>1, b=>2, c=>3'::hstore - ARRAY['a','b']
'a=>1, b=>2, c=>3'::hstore - 'a=>4, b=>2'::hstore
```

In the statement

```
UPDATE mytable SET properties = properties - 'key' where label = '9912345678';
```

the string `'key'` may be resolved as `text` or `hstore`. The first choice of the hstore algorithm is `hstore`, so the statement is resolved to

```
UPDATE mytable SET properties = properties - 'key'::hstore where label = '9912345678';
```

and raises the error

```
ERROR:  Unexpected end of string
```

though the error message could be more informative, like `Unexpected end of string while parsing hstore constant.`

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any more information on your remark `The operator is overloaded so the right-hand operand should be explicitly cast.` ?

Comment: Consider the ambiguity in '{a,b}' - is that a single key or an array of two?

Comment: @BartFriederichs - the operator is ambiguous, I have added how the operand is resolved in this case.